# Losing information while converting Time.at(ts).in_time_zone(time_zone) to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, time

While converting a time in a certain time zone to string, I am loosing some information I need.

Example:

```
ts = Time.now.to_i
time_zone = "America/Los_Angeles"
time = Time.now.in_time_zone(time_zone)
time_string = time.to_s
```

Output:

```
time 
#=> Tue, 31 Mar 2015 12:05:03 PDT -07:00
time_string 
#=> "2015-03-31 12:05:03 -0700"
```

How can I get time string to be equal to `Tue, 31 Mar 2015 12:05:03 PDT -07:00`?

Comment: Checkout [`Time#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) using this you can format the string anyway you see fit.

Comment: You should add an ActiceSupport or Rails tag.  That probably would prompt additional answers.

Comment: With no Rails or ActiveSupport tag, the implicit assumption is that you want a pure-Ruby solution.  Your example, however, suggests to those who know Rails that you are open to a solution that uses ActiveSupport methods. That's why you need an ActiveSupport or Rails tag. Also, readers who only look at questions with ActiveSupport or Rails tags may skip yours.

Answer (score 1):

As engineersmnky said, strftime is your friend:

```
time_string = time_string.to_time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S PDT %z")
```

But I'm not really sure about the zone %z!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone(time_zone).strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
"Tue, 31 Mar 2015 12:59:25 PDT"
```